# How to show preview of image using handler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

I m using a handler to display images on my page from database

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XYZ"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Image from EmployeeInfo where Emp_Id = @ID";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlParameter ImageID = new SqlParameter("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Ht"]);
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Wt"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.HasRows)
    {
        dReader.Read();
        byte[] imagethumbnail = null;
        try
        {
            imagethumbnail = MakeThumbnail((byte[])dReader["Image"], width, height);
        }
        catch
        {             
        }
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imagethumbnail);        
    }
    dReader.Close();
    con.Close();
}

public static byte[] MakeThumbnail(byte[] myImage, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight)
{
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    using (Image thumbnail = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(myImage)).GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null, new IntPtr()))
    {
        thumbnail.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This code works fine when displaying images from database.
Now What I want to do is to Show image preview using a different Handler.
Now if u look at the above code then you can see we have image data in byte[] form.
I m uploading a image and I m able to get the data in byte[] but this data of mine is on .cs page.

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(imagethumbnail);
```

If I use this command converting data into bytes from page, it shows me the image on page nothing else.
Can you give me any idea how to show this data into image?

There is nothing much change in the datastream
This is what I want to use but how to get byte[] from .cs page to handler.

```
 imagethumbnail = MakeThumbnail((byte[])dReader["Image"], width, height);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imagethumbnail);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can seperate your database image logic into a Generic Handler (ASHX) and then use the handler as your image's `src` e.g.

```
<img src="GetImage.ashx?id=1"/>
```

You'd need to create GetImage.ashx and handle your id's (or whatever your using) appropriately.  Then you can do a simple write back to the page.

This will allow you to dynamically pull an image from the database while using it as a seperate element on your page.

Comment: I m using a uploader to upload an image using ajax popup Extender.
When I click on the upload button on this extender the event is fired and the data I can retrive in this event code.
I want this data in my handler

Comment: I know that I will have to use another handler but I dont know how to pass data to that handler this is what my problem is

Comment: Can you post the data to a second handler async?

Comment: There is nothing much change in the datastream
check the above edit